# Colouring Specific Text In Photoshop using scripts

Tags: javascript, vb.net, photoshop-script

I have created a piece of code in VB.Net to create a wall of text.

[image]

The text is saved in a .txt file. What I'd like to do is copy into a text layer in photoshop and highlight only certain words (to give it an effect of "syntaxing" like in the image).

I have tried writing scripts by I'm afraid I just can't get a nice prompt to do what I want it to do :/. I'd like to have a textbox for the "wall of text", textbox for a the hex value of a colour and another textbox to choose what phrase / word to highlight.

VB.NET code :

```
Imports System.Console
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
Dim lines As Integer
Dim imported As Integer
Dim wallLines As Integer
Dim wallWords As Integer
Dim sourceName As String
Dim random As New Random
Dim randomLine As Integer
Dim randomPhrase As String

Sub Main()
    WriteLine("         Welcome to Text Wall Generator by E.Skalinski")
    WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    WriteLine("Please enter the name of the .txt file you have saved your text into:")
    WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    WriteLine("       WARNING previous generated walls will be overwritten!")
    WriteLine("    (please make sure each phrase / word is on a seperate line!)")
    sourceName = ReadLine()
    Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(sourceName, FileMode.Open)
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        sr.ReadLine()
        lines = lines + 1
    End While
    sr.Close()
    Dim sr2 As New System.IO.StreamReader(sourceName, FileMode.Open)
    Dim phrases(lines - 1) As String
    For i = 0 To lines - 1 Step 1
        phrases(i) = sr2.ReadLine()
    Next i
    sr2.Close()
    WriteLine("Imported:")
    For i = 0 To lines - 1
        imported = i
        WriteLine("Line:" & imported & " " & phrases(i))
    Next i
    WriteLine("How many lines would you like to generate?")
    wallLines = ReadLine()
    WriteLine("How many words / phrases per line?")
    wallWords = ReadLine()
    Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("wall.txt", False)
    Dim wall(wallLines - 1, wallWords - 1) As String
    For i = 0 To wallLines - 1 Step 1
        For j = 0 To wallWords - 1 Step 1
            randomLine = random.Next(0, lines)
            randomPhrase = phrases(randomLine)
            wall(i, j) = randomPhrase
            If j = wallWords - 1 Then
                sw.WriteLine(wall(i, j))
            Else
                sw.Write(wall(i, j) & " ")
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    sw.Close()
    WriteLine("Generated (file name : wall.txt')")
    ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Java Script Code attempt:

```
doc = app.activeDocument;

var myWindow = new Window ("dialog","HighlightWord",undefined,{closeButton:true});

var group = myWindow.add ("group");
group.alignment = "right";
group.add ("statictext", undefined, "Text:");
var maxSize = group.add ("edittext",undefined, );
group.add ("statictext", undefined, "");

group = myWindow.add ("group");
group.alignment = "right";
group.add ("statictext", undefined, "Word / phrase to highlight");
var minSize = group.add ("edittext",undefined, );
group.add ("statictext", undefined, " ");


group = myWindow.add ("group");
group.alignment = "right";
group.add ("statictext", undefined, "Hex color");
var minSize = group.add ("edittext",undefined, );
group.add ("statictext", undefined, " ");

myWindow.show ()
```

Comment: It would be MUCH easier to load the text file into a textbox, do the formatting there and then take a screenshot and save it as jpg...

Comment: The thing is I don't want to do that because I want it done multiple times. :P

Comment: I fail to see how processing something multiple times excludes my suggestion.

Comment: If you mean you want multiple colors you can use a rich textbox.

Comment: your JS code is only for showing a window to collect inputs - Do you have code to apply the inputs to the text layer or is this where you are stuck?

Comment: Yes that's where I'm stuck. I've thought of using text ranges.